# How to return various types from service but with the same part?

Tags: c#, wcf

I return various types from my service:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Initialize();

    [OperationContract]
    Settings GetSettings(); // returns custom type Settings

    [OperationContract]
    void SetSettings(Settings settings);

    [OperationContract]
    bool SettingsAccepted();
}
```

But I want to introduce status codes for my service that is not built on WCF infrastructure but on my service's inner logic, like this:

```
[DataContract]
public enum ServiceStatus
{
    [EnumMember]
    NormalWork = 0,

    [EnumMember]
    TimeOut,

    [EnumMember]
    DenialOfService
};
```

And I want my service to return not just void, bool or custom type, but them with status code, like this (pseudo code):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    (ServiceStatus) Initialize();

    [OperationContract]
    (ServiceStatus, Settings) GetSettings();

    [OperationContract]
    (ServiceStatus) SetSettings(Settings settings);

    [OperationContract]
    (ServiceStatus, bool) SettingsAccepted();
}
```

Client's logic will be like this: check the status code in returned message and if it is ServiceStatus.NormalWork then do work with the rest part of returned message.

How best to organize it? Have I introduce a base class to return (with DataContract attribute) and then create new derived class from it per each return value (per each operation contract)? Or is there a better approach? Maybe there is a built in infrastructure in WCF for task like this - to return custom status codes together with custom return types?

Comment: Confusing.. is it C# code deceleration [(ServiceStatus, Settings)] ??

    [OperationContract]
    (ServiceStatus, Settings) GetSettings();

Comment: It is somewhat pseudocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Client's logic will be like this: check the status code in returned message and if it is ServiceStatus.NormalWork then do work with the rest part of returned message.

If you really want this, the other answer has all the details to create such a beast. **However**, please do not do this. If your service is not working normally, throw an exception. It will be translated to a fault automatically.

Return codes are so 1980. I *already* have to have exception handling. Your service may be unavailable, the network may be down or there may be any other failure. So I already have exception handling and now with your proposed method, I need exception handling **and** return code handling. With every single call. That sucks. In addition, people may make mistakes easier. They might just take the delivered values and forget to check your return code. With exceptions, that mistake will never happen.

If you want your service to fail with an error that says "DenialOfService", then please create a `DenialOfServiceException` and throw that. Don't use return codes. That's not the WCF way to report errors.

---

If you do want to have a fixed structure, you can use the template approach of the other answer, or you can use inheritance:

```
[DataContract]
public class ServiceResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public ServiceStatus Status { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class SettingsAcceptedResponse : ServiceResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool Result { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    // [...] 

    [OperationContract]
    ServiceResponse SetSettings(Settings settings);

    [OperationContract]
    SettingsAcceptedResponse SettingsAccepted();
}
```

Comment: The puprose I want to introduce the status codes is laying less in error notification and more in status notification. "Denial of service" was a bad example... hmm, how about just informing about the various statuses of normal operation? In this case are exceptions still a better choice in compare with status codes?

Comment: Maybe you're right when you're speaking about status codes - I mark you recommendation as useful - but what I really asked was about how to receive data with various types without creating class per such a type - i.e. in somehow generic manner.

Comment: @Alex34758 Added an example of how you *can* do it.

Comment: Your example is what I called "class per returned type". To me it seems that generic approach is little better. Thanks anyway.

Comment: "generic approach is little better" from the service point of view, but on the client side types returned from service is a little bit clumsy... Well, maybe KnownType and data contract resolvers is better. There is a room to thought about...

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create class called `ServiceResponse<T>` and with properties you need to have status and property of type `T` where will be real returned object.

Of course in this approach all your methods will return `ServiceResponse<bool>` when result will be of type `bool`

It may looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class ServiceResponse<T>
{
  [DataMember]
  ServiceStatus Status { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  T Payload { get; set; }
}
```

This class could contain also messages to user, exceptions, erros and anything that could be usefull to handle properly response from WCF.

Then usage in WCF would be:

```
[OperationContract]
    ServiceResponse<bool> SettingsAccepted();
```

Comment: Is it that is called ["bounded jenerics"](http://jeffbarnes.net/blog/post/2007/05/10/WCF-Serialization-and-Generics.aspx)?

Comment: I think it is indeed.